# Within an EPUB file, what would <guide> mean?

Tags: epub

I've been given a few defining tags that would be found in an EPUB file and I have to say what they mean. I've never come across the  tag before and can't find a reference to it anywhere. Is my prof just to catch us out?

Answer (score 2):

The `<guide>` element in the content.opf file is part of EPUB2 and has been deprecated in EPUB3 in favor of the `<nav epub:type="landmarks">` element in the nav document (the one with properties="nav" in the manifest).

Both `<guide>` and `<nav epub:type="landmarks">` elements identify pages/sections of the book as serving a particular role, such as title page, dedication, forward, first page of text.

Here are links to each in the EPUB3 documentation

http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-publications.html#sec-guide-elem

http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-contentdocs.html#sec-xhtml-nav-def-types-landmarks